# SQL - Transpose different rows in columns

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot

I have 1 table (I can not modify it before) from a bulk insert, and I need to transpose all the rows in "VALUES" column into single columns. Except for the "YEAR" (going from 0 to 50) and the "VALUES" columns, the other 3 columns are filled with a unique value (example: in year 0 size is 'L', color is 'red' and price is '10' and this size,color and price values are constant for all my 50 years).

The input table is like this:

[image: Excel Input Table]

I would like to have as output all the "VALUES" in columns called for example "VALUE_0" "VALUE_1" "VALUE_2" "VALUE_3" etc, where the numbers 0,1,2,3 stand for the year considered.

```
CREATE TABLE #CURVE(
    YEAR INT, 
    SIZE VARCHAR(100),
    COLOR VARCHAR(100),
    PRICE VARCHAR(100), 
    VALUES FLOAT
)
```

The Output should be:

[image: Excel Output Table]

Comment: you should take a look at pivot  table  ..

Comment: Please only tag a single RDBMS i.e. either MySQL or SQL Server - not both.

Comment: Hello AbbaB, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide sample data and expected results, as tabular text.

Comment: I've removed MySQL and SQL Server - please only add the relevant one back.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    size,
    color, 
    price,
    max(case when year = 0 then value end) value_0,
    max(case when year = 1 then value end) value_1,
    max(case when year = 2 then value end) value_2,
    max(case when year = 3 then value end) value_3,
    max(case when year = 4 then value end) value_4,
    max(case when year = 5 then value end) value_5
from #curve
group by size, color, price
```

You can easily extend the `select` clause to handle more years.

This is a cross-database solution, that usually performs as good or better than vendor-specific implementations of `pivot`. On top of that (and for what it's worth), I find it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

we need to know how many values do you expect in Values column for a year?
Otherwise the query looks like this:

```
SELECT [YEAR], [SIZE], [COLOR], [PRICE], [1] as [Value1], [2] as [Value2], [3] as [Value3]
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [YEAR], [SIZE], [COLOR], [PRICE] ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ID
    FROM #CURVE c
) t
PIVOT(MAX([Value]) FOR ID IN ([1], [2], [3]])) p
```